# Procedure to "Add non duplicate column values" oracle

Tags: oracle

I wrote a procedure in mysql to check for any duplicate values in table so that same ones can't be added.Here it is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_valu (c_cntry_id IN COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID%TYPE,
                                       c_cntr_name IN COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE, 
                                       c_rgn_id IN COUNTRIES.REGION_ID%TYPE)

IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO countries(COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY_NAME,REGION_ID)
    values (user_seq.nextval, c_cntr_name,c_rgn_id);
  c_cntry_id := user_seq.currval;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN dup_val_on_index
  THEN 
    c_cntry_id := null;
END;
/
```

Can someone please help me with writing a similar procedure in oracle? I am actually new to oracle.Some guidance needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to add a new row to `user_info` if one does not already exist with the specified `name`, `email`, and `extension`?  Does your table have a unique constraint on those three columns?  If not, why not?  If so, do you just want to try the insert and catch the exception or do you expect attempts to insert duplicates to be common?

Comment: Yes,I do have a constraint in my table on "Extension" column(which is my PK),so I only want to avoid inserting duplicate "Extension" values.Yes,I only want to insert and if not inserted,catch an exception.

Comment: In your edited procedure, the first parameter is no longer an `OUT` parameter, it is an `IN` parameter.  You can't assign a value to an `OUT` parameter.  I would guess that you want the first parameter to go back to being an `OUT` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to try the `insert` and catch the exception when your key is violated.  Assuming that the vast majority of the time people are not trying to insert a value that already exists, this should be reasonably efficient.  If most of the calls to the procedure result in exceptions being thrown or caught, however, you may be spending most of your time doing exception handling and you may want to do a `merge` instead of an `insert`.

I've changed your parameter names to use a `p_` prefix.  That saves you from bugs when your parameter names conflict with the name of a column in the table in which case Oracle will reference the column when you might be intending to use the column name.  In your example, assuming `name` is a column in the table, every reference to `name` would be referring to the column in the table and none would be referencing the parameter to the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_values (p_UserID OUT VARCHAR2,
                                        p_name IN VARCHAR2, 
                                        p_email IN VARCHAR2,
                                        p_extension IN VARCHAR2)

IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO User_Info( userID, name, email, extension, create_date )
    values (user_seq.nextval, p_Name,p_Email,p_Extension,sysdate);
  p_userID := user_seq.currval;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN dup_val_on_index
  THEN 
    p_userID := null;
END;
```

If you are using (or need to support) an old version of Oracle, you may not be able to assign the `currval` of the sequence like this.  You might have to

```
SELECT user_seq.currval
  INTO p_userID
  FROM dual;
```

instead of

```
  p_userID := user_seq.currval;
```

Comment: Another option is to use the `IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX` hint

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Possible, sure.  That hint scares the living heck out of me, though.  Hints that change functional behavior rather than just influencing query plans or giving the optimizer additional information are scary.  If catching the exception is too inefficient in a particular environment, I'd much prefer to do a `merge` rather than an `insert` or to code a `select` before the `insert`.

Comment: @Justin Cave: Getting error "sequence does not exist".My question: should I create a sequence first?

Comment: @user3400060 Yes.  If you want to use a sequence, you have to create it first.

Comment: Ok,can you plz suggest,in my case,what should I keep "Minvalue" and "MaxValue" and also "INCREMENT BY" for this? I am thinking 1,999999 and 1?

Comment: @user3400060 If you're not sure, the defaults are generally good.  Just 'create sequence user_seq'.

Comment: tx,I created and that error disappeared.However,I am getting a different one saying "PL-00363:expression C_CNTRY_ID cannot be used as an assigned target" (I edited my procedure code).Can you please guide?